# Travelling to Germany as a tourist with my spouse whilst they are on a business visa

Tags: schengen, spouses, nepali-citizens

My husband is going Germany for his sales mission in Berlin. It's his first foreign trip. I also want to travel with him but maybe the embassy will suspect me as now I'm neither studying nor doing any kind of work.

How can I make the process to travel with my husband?

Comment: For visa-related questions, it is always helpful to state your nationality, as the answer depends on it. Also, it may be helpful to give an idea what answer you expect. "Accompanying your husband on a business" trip is a valid reason for travel an you make a visa application as usual. Just don't lie on your visa application.

Comment: I'm from Nepal. I juss want to know if they will provide me with the tourist visa . As it is the 1st trip of my husband as well. I have heard it somewhere that I have a low chances of getting visa.

Comment: What visa does your husband have?

Comment: Will get to know by the Monday 13th February.. if he ll get the multiple visa or business visa then it might not be difcult for me to proceed for tourists visa .If he ll get the tourist visa then . How can I apply.

Comment: One thing that many governments use as a primary criteria is proof you will go home.  You being at home, gives your husband cause to return.  Both of you traveling to Germany lessens that angle (unless you have kids, own a nice house, etc).

Comment: We don't have kids.we have got married 9 months back. Yeah we do have a plan to return home for sure. But it's not in our hand may be emabsy will suspect me. How can I prepare myslef to meet the criteria and make them convinced.

Answer (score 2):

There are many spouses who do not work, and there are quite a few of them who travel with their spouses. Your situation is not unheard of. Of course consular officers by nature will scrutinize people without jobs a little more however it's normal.

Apply with the same supporting documents that a typical candidate will provide showing signs of ties to your home country.

*- Ownership of real property (real estate) etc
- Ownership of a business/investment/etc.
- Responsibilities & relationships (e.g.: caring for parents, community involvement, etc.)*

Think of as many as you can and have documentation if possible. Also I think it might be a good idea if possible to let your husband apply **first** and get his visa, then you apply because objectively without your husband getting a visa, it is unlikely you will be issued one yourself so you will save yourself the cost.

Comment: Thank you so much for the proper guidance. So I'm now thinking of making of no objection letter from my previous college..